# Racket: `provide` using a lambda to discriminate

Tags: export, racket

I have a bunch of `define`s in a `utils.rkt` file.  Some of these are helper functions, and I do not really want to `provide` them.  I've looked through the docs (https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html) and it looks like `provide` and `#%provide` need an explicit list of all forms I want to exclude.  I already prefix an underscore to the name of every helper, so they end up having names like `_foo`, `_bar`, and `_baz`.

Mapping `provide` over `(filter not-helper-p (module->exports my-module))` seemed like a good thing to try, but `racket` complains `provide: not at module level`.  I've also poured over documentation on [namespaces](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html), [module names and loading](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html), and [provide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-provide.html).

```lisp
(define (foo x)
  (_foo x 0))

(define (_foo x y)
  (+ x y))
```

In this example I want a simple way to only provide things bound to symbols without an underscore prefix.  So I should only provide `foo`.  In practice, I have a lot of these, and it would be a pain to exclude them all explicitly by name.

I'm relatively new to `racket`: is there a more common pattern for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: Usually you give `provide` an explicit list of identifiers to *export*, not ones to *exclude*...

Comment: `(provide (contract-out [foo (-> number? number?)]))`, just `(provide foo)` if you're not using contracts, etc.

Comment: @Shawn In practice I have a lot of functions to `provide`.  My question is asking if there is a more efficient way to do it given the fact that I am trying to export only symbols whose name matches a certain regex.

Comment: So just go through and add the ones you want to export to the `provide` list. I usually add each public function as I write it (along with `rackunit` test cases, etc.) so the needed contract (if any) is fresh in my mind.

Comment: You do see a lot of old scheme code that uses naming conventions (a leading `%` is common) to separate functions that are part of a public API from internal ones, but that's not needed in Racket, R6RS or R7RS thanks to those having module systems. Don't try to emulate obsolete practices.

Comment: I'm aware that what I want can be accomplished by writing the explicit list of `provide`s.  That's not my question.  My question has the form "is it possible to do X?".  Is your answer "no"?

Comment: *is there a more common pattern for doing this sort of thing?* I'm telling you what that is.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and for your answer.